# How to get the mean of subtraction of 2 dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes in python,

**y**

```
2015-06-05 15:00:00.000     20.22
2015-06-05 15:00:00.500     20.22
2015-06-05 15:00:01.000     20.22
                            ...  
2015-06-05 15:31:38.500    114.95
2015-06-05 15:31:39.000    114.95
2015-06-05 15:31:39.500    114.95
Freq: 500L, Name: sensor_19, dtype: float64
```

**y_predict**

```
2015-06-05 15:00:00.000     93.445314
2015-06-05 15:00:00.500     20.224281
2015-06-05 15:00:01.000     20.226055
                              ...    
2015-06-05 15:31:38.500    115.612101
2015-06-05 15:31:39.000    114.682510
2015-06-05 15:31:39.500    114.917647
Freq: 500L, dtype: float64
```

Actually, **y_predict** are predicted values of **y**, computed by an ARMA model. So as you can see, they have the same data structure, the same number of lines, the same index. However, when I tried to get the mean of substraction of these 2 dataframes, I got an error.

```
def mean_forecast_err(y, y_predict):
   return y.sub(y_predict).mean()

# other preparation before ...
y = df['sensor_19']
arma_mod12 = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, (1, 2)).fit()
y_predict12 = arma_mod12.predict()
print "ARMA(1, 2): err_mean=" + mean_forecast_err(y, y_predict12)
```

My questions are :

- Where does the error come from ?
- Or how to generate an appreciated exception, so that I can see the error message for debugging ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. I only changed the return value to type str in the last line of code:

```
def mean_forecast_err(y, y_predict):
   return y.sub(y_predict).mean()

# other preparation before ...
y = df['sensor_19']
arma_mod12 = sm.tsa.ARMA(y, (1, 2)).fit()
y_predict12 = arma_mod12.predict()
print "ARMA(1, 2): err_mean=" + str(mean_forecast_err(y, y_predict12))
```